# Facebook communication to Application

Tags: facebook-graph-api

The start-up i currently work for is oriented around restaurant wait times. For our v1.25 specifications our clients -restaurants- that have Facebook pages want to be able to communicate to their app profile from their Facebook page.

The closest i have came to answering this question is the Graph API. However, the Graph API only allows us to read and write data to FB pages.  So, is there a way for a restaurants FB page to write to its app profile? Secondly, Loso, whom we have modeled some of our designs from has this ability, does anyone have an idea as to how they have done it?

--Boris M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option that you can consider...  
When you are designing the app you can also develop a page tab to go with it...
You will find this option in the basic settings of the app.
You can make it to install for all first time users of your app, by getting a list of all his pages he created using that profile then install it on the one he selects.

This page tab when installed on a page will appears just where other tabs on the page appers(e.g. events, notes etc. occurs)
You can provide your required functionality on this tab as you like.
Thus the user can just select that tab on the page and use its functionality to post on the profile page of the app.

Hope this works for you... and also u can check out the jobcaster app it does something like that!